# Use scrollTop() twice at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I use `animate ({ scrollTop() })` to scroll multiple DIVs at the same time?

Example if I run the below `goTOP(){;` function. I want to scroll to the top of the page and at the same time scroll to the top of `#studentName` TABLE.

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="studentName">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-md-2">ID</th>
      <th class="col-md-2">Subject</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

#studentName is having a scrollbar **[EDIT]**

```
#studentName{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

jQuery: This is what I've tried so far. Does not work as expected.

```
function goTOP(){
  $('html, body').animate({ 'scrollTop' : 0 }, 700);//go top of page
  $('html, body').animate({ 'scrollTop' : $('#studentName').first().offset().top }, 100); // go to top level of this DIV
}
```

Comment: Can someone help please? None of the answers are complete answers. The table `#studentName`does not scroll top the top. As you can see I've used `overflow-y: scroll;`. So I need to go to the top level of `#studentName` when `goTOP()` functions is called. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

```
function goTOP(){
  $('html, body').animate({ 'scrollTop' : 0 }, 700);//go top of page
  $('#studentName tbody').animate({ 'scrollTop': 0 }, 100); // go to top level of this DIV
}
```

Comment: Doesn't scroll to the top of the TABLE? This `$('#studentName').animate({ 'scrollTop': 0 }, 100); ` doesn't scroll.

Comment: What is the ID of the div?

Comment: Thanks. The table ID is `studentName` wrapped inside DIV with an ID `studentList`. I want to scroll to the top of the TABLE.

Comment: Try it with the the id #studentList. The thing that is scrollable is the div, right? I made the change in the example code above.

Comment: all records (text) is in `<tbody></tbody>`. The scroll-bar scrolls the `<tbody></tbody>` items.

Comment: Can you post the actual code to a jsfiddle? I can get an answer to your much more easily that way.

Comment: I also made another attempt in my original post. Try that before you put any effort into jsfiddle